# Can I make a SingleActiveRegion without help from the view?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I've got a region adapter for a fluent `RibbonTabItem` and I want it show only a single `RibbonGroupBox` at a time. I expected this to do the job:

```
    protected override IRegion CreateRegion()
    {
        return new SingleActiveRegion();
    }
```

but it doesn't work (i.e. whenever I navigate the region to a new view, I get an *additional* new view), unless I make my views implement `IRegionMemberLifetime` and return `false` from `KeepAlive`.

Question: what do I miss? how to create a region that always clears its `ViewsCollection` before adding a new view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I should have observed `ActiveViews` (not `Views`) of my region... works fine now.

Here's the full code:

```
public class RibbonTabItemRegionAdapter : RegionAdapterBase<RibbonTabItem>
{
    public RibbonTabItemRegionAdapter( IRegionBehaviorFactory regionBehaviorFactory ) : base( regionBehaviorFactory )
    {
    }

    protected override void Adapt( IRegion region, RibbonTabItem regionTarget )
    {
        region.ActiveViews.CollectionChanged += ( s, e ) =>
                                                {
                                                    switch (e.Action)
                                                    {
                                                        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                                                            foreach (var newItem in e.NewItems)
                                                                regionTarget.Groups.Add( (RibbonGroupBox)newItem );
                                                            break;
                                                        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                                                            foreach (var oldItem in e.OldItems)
                                                                regionTarget.Groups.Remove( (RibbonGroupBox)oldItem );
                                                            break;
                                                    }
                                                };
    }

    protected override IRegion CreateRegion()
    {
        return new SingleActiveRegion();
    }
}
```